# Does this sentence sound fine? "Because of its transparency, we hardly see the problem"

Tags: sentence-construction

I am writing about the importance of learning English vocabulary, and I have this idea:

> Just like the air, language as a medium is rarely noticed when we use it. It needs to be embedded into our daily practice to be useful. **But because of its transparency, we hardly see the problem.**

For clarification, the language here is transparency, or invisible, just like the air. People think that they can learn vocabulary just enough to communicate, but in fact it's not. The problem here is that it's not, but they quite confident that it is. Same as air pollution.

My native friend doesn't feel complete, but he can't think of a way to convey this message in a simple statement. Can you tell me where it's wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: For clarification, what is the "problem" you are referring to in the final sentence?

Comment: I can't tell what "language transparency" would be. You don't realize language functionality in daily use? The quote by itself may be difficult to comprehend.

Comment: What is the "problem" that we "hardly see?"

Comment: ***Transparency*** isn't really an appropriate word here, since in the context of language, a "transparent" usage means one which is easily recognised and understood. You can probably assume from the lack of decent answers to [Word for something so familiar or ubiquitous that it goes unnoticed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214539/) that English doesn't really have a concise way of referring to the phenomenon you're thinking of.

Comment: _But because of **this ubiquity** (or ubiquitousness), we hardly see the problem_ works a treat here, but see the link provided by FumbleFingers.

Comment: @eelero see my update

Comment: @P.E.Dant see my update

Comment: @user3169 see my update

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'll use your answer. Do you want to make it as an answer?

Comment: @Ooker I don't think **ubiquity** is a perfect fit. Close, but no cigar. Not worthy of an answer, it seems to me.

Comment: @P.E.Dant how about _because we aren't aware of it, we hardly see the problem_?

Comment: @Ooker Something incorporating _like the very air we breathe_ would be more expressive of the thought you're trying to convey here.

Comment: @Ooker - Here's a start: _Just as we rarely notice the air we breathe, we rarely notice the medium of language as we speak. It must be embedded in our lives to be useful, but because it is as transparent and ubiquitous as air..._

Comment: @P.E.Dant oh can't it be an answer? It's hitting hard

Comment: @Ooker - You finish it. You're here to learn!

Comment: @P.E.Dant I just don't want to take your rep, that's all

Comment: My rep is of no moment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[P. E. Dant suggests this:](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98282/does-this-sentence-sound-fine-because-of-its-transparency-we-hardly-see-the-p?noredirect=1#comment192816_98282)

> Just as we rarely notice the air we breathe, we rarely notice the medium of language as we speak. It must be embedded in our lives to be useful, **but because it is as transparent and ubiquitous as air...**

...we hardly see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would not put some words of that short paragraph. For example, when you say, **language as a medium** what exactly do you mean? a medium of communication?

The other word would be **embedded** I would put *It needs to be inside of our daily routine to be useful*

Comment: I feel that *embedded into* works much better than *inside* here. No one refers to items as being "inside" a routine.

Comment: Now you say it, it takes another meaning. In fact, I think I will put **It needs to be part of our daily routine**.

Comment: @eelero - We would not use **into** with embedded. **Embedded** takes **in**.

Comment: @P.E.Dant It might not be formal or technically correct, but I've heard it used with **into** many times.

Comment: @eelero You might hear _into_ from a non-native speaker who is trying out new verbs, but  (subject to my misgivings about them) [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embedded+in%2Cembedded+into%2Cembedded+within&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cembedded%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembedded%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembedded%20within%3B%2Cc0) have it as rarer even than _within_, which itself is extremely rare. A native speaker (who is familiar with the verb) will not use _into_.

Answer (score 0):

I can't shrink this idea down to one word, but how about:

> Just like the air, language as a medium is rarely noticed when we use it. It needs to be embedded into our daily practice to be useful. But **because its true meaning/usefulness is hidden**, we hardly see the problem.